# Object to group id in MongoDB pipelines

Tags: mongodb, serialization, concatenation

I have a MongoDB aggregation pipeline that returns such an output:

```
 [
    {
        "id": {
            "isPaid": false,
            "state": "approved",
            "updatedAt": "2018-06-27"
        },
        "state": "approved",
        "isPaid": false,
        "updatedAt": "2018-06-27",
        "totalCount": 1,
        "totalValue": 658.4332
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "isPaid": false,
            "state": "canceled",
            "updatedAt": "2018-05-30"
        },
        "state": "canceled",
        "isPaid": false,
        "updatedAt": "2018-05-30",
        "totalCount": 1,
        "totalValue": 1735.7175
    },
]
```

For the system that exploits it, I'd need `id` to be available, as a string.

So I'm wondering if, using an aggregation pipeline stage, there would be an elegant and generic way to concatenate/serialize object values to a string:

`"id": {"isPaid": false, "state": "approved", "updatedAt": "2018-06-27"}`
to something like:
`"id": "0.approved.2018-06-27"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `$concat`

```
db.t55.aggregate([
    {$addFields : {
        id : {$concat : [{$cond :["$isPaid", "1","0"]}, ".", "$state", "." ,"$updatedAt"]}
    }}
])
```

using `$toString` if not just true/false

```
db.t55.aggregate([
    {$addFields : {
        id : {$concat : [{$toString :{$indexOfArray : [[false,true], "$isPaid"]}}, ".", "$state", "." ,"$updatedAt"]}
    }}
])
```

output

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c3e794b21526e3ff4bf4ca2"), "id" : "0.approved.2018-06-27", "state" : "approved", "isPaid" : false, "updatedAt" : "2018-06-27", "totalCount" : 1, "totalValue" : 658.4332 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c3e794b21526e3ff4bf4ca3"), "id" : "0.canceled.2018-05-30", "state" : "canceled", "isPaid" : false, "updatedAt" : "2018-05-30", "totalCount" : 1, "totalValue" : 1735.7175 }
```

Comment: As I thought... Not exactly generic, in the sense it's not something that could browse the object values, map and join them directly, but I believe there's no short way to do such a thing with the MongoDB functions set.